# Can't install linux-libc-dev on WSL/Bash on Ubuntu on Windows

Tags: linux, windows-10, ubuntu, bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to install linux-libc-dev on Bash on Ubuntu on Windows (the Windows Subsystem for Linux).
This is to fix an earlier bash error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libc6-dev : Depends: linux-libc-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I've tried to fix the broken package through `sudo apt-get -f install`:

```
Unpacking linux-libc-dev:amd64 (4.4.0-119.143) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-libc-dev_4.4.0-119.143_amd64.deb (--unpack):
unable to create '/usr/include/linux/netfilter/xt_tcpmss.h.dpkg-new' (while processing './usr/include/linux/netfilter/xt_tcpmss.h'): Input/output error
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I've tried uninstalling/reinstalling Bash on Ubuntu on Windows in cmd using:

```
lxrun /uninstall
lxrun /install
```

However, the problem persists even after re-installing.
I've also tried manually installing the cached deb file through

```
sudo dpkg -i /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-libc-dev_4.4.0-119.143_amd64.deb
```

but this understandably results in the same error. 
The same goes for

```
sudo apt-get install linux-libc-dev
```

Any suggestions are very much appreciated.

Comment: The `Input/output error` message suggests that you have a disc error, so run a file system check (this will need to be done at boot time or from an external disc. It is also worth doing `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade` afterwards to get the latest dependency lists and releases.

Comment: What do you mean when you say `sudo dpkg -i </var/cache/apt/archives/linux-libc-dev_4.4.0-119.143_amd64.deb>.deb`?  Are you actually typing `<` and `>`? Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer.

Comment: @AFH Can you provide any specific pointers for how to perform a file system check for [WSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux)? As far as I know WSL doesn't actually boot...

Comment: @Scott I've edited the question. But no, I'm not typing `<` and `>`... First time posting a question on SE so I'm lacking experience/making a few formatting mistakes...